Electric circuits: voltage connection
The intuitive answer to this question is to connect the voltmeter in parallel to the battery. However, the official answer says: the voltmeter is connected to the right of the battery, between the battery and the bell push. Can someone please help me understand what this answer means? I think the statement "The voltmeter is connected so that the bell push does not affect the reading" is a bit tricky. thank you  

Clearly a mistake in the answer key.

If the crossed element on the schema is a voltmeter then it shows zero while the switch is not pressed. That's not good.

@user13964273 what are you saying? (I suspect the crossed element is an indicator light).

Your "intuitive answer" is correct. A volt meter must connect to two different circuit nodes in order to give a non-zero reading. (E.G., to the circuit nodes on either side of the battery or, as you say, "in parallel to the battery.") There is only one circuit node "between the battery and the bell push." What other node might the author have had in mind?
Many circuits have a designated "ground" node. When a ground node is specified, and when somebody asks you to measure the voltage at some point in a circuit, what they really are asking is for you to measure the voltage between that point and ground.
Your example circuit does not have an explicit, designated ground, but maybe the person who wrote the question was thinking of the left hand node as ground. In battery powered circuits, it is very common for one terminal of the battery to be connected to "ground," and the other terminal to be switched. OTOH, it's usually the negative side of the battery that's grounded and the positive side that's switched, but in your example, it's the negative side that's switched.
All in all, I'd say it's a poorly written question. Your best strategy woud be to speak to the person who assigned it to you. Explain to them your idea that the meter should be connected in parallel with the battery, and ask them how to express that idea in language that will satisfy them.

yep, bad question because in real life the battery has an internal resistance and when you push the button both bell and light will draw current making the voltage reading change.

@Peltio, Ha! In other words, you're saying it's a trick question, and there is no connection that could ensure "that the bell push does not affect the reading." If I were an instructor, I might give extra credit for that observation, but I'd also give full credit to any student who assumed that the battery symbol, like most of the circuit symbols they will see in their assignments, represents an idealized component.

@Peltio Hmm, your words made me think: Does that mean pushing the button will change/affect the voltage of the battery (due to having internal resistance), so connecting the voltmeter in parallel to the battery will have a changed/affected reading every time the button is pushed? This could be an explanation to the sentence 'he voltmeter is connected so that the bell push does not affect the reading'. However, still, connecting the voltmeter to the copper wires (as the mark scheme says) will give zero, which is what I don't get.

@SalmaAbdelazizAbdeldayem, Every real-world battery has behavior that we call, "internal resistance." The voltage drops by an amount that is approximately proportional to the current that it supplies. There is no way to avoid that voltage drop. But, when we draw circuit diagrams, and especially when you encounter circuit diagrams in classes, we often assume ideal behavior for the components in the diagram. E.g., A battery is assumed to act like an ideal voltage source. We assume that its voltage is an absolute constant regardless of current.

P.S., When we're designing circuits, the real behavior of components often is close enough to the ideal that we don't care. But sometimes, the difference matters. Sometimes you'll see diagrams that show "parasitic" or "phantom" components—components that are not physically present in the real circuit, but which help to explain how the real circuit behaves. E.g., There always is a tiny amount of capacitance between any two conductors. If it matters, the designer may draw a parasitic capacitor between the two wires to make simulation of the circuit more accurate.
